# Nifi data provenance in Apache NiFi Processors goes away. Anyway to stop it from doing that?

Tags: xml, apache-nifi

Data provenance in Apache NiFi Processors information goes away after a few minutes automatically.  Is there a setting that I can set to a longer period? We need this data for some debugging.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Provenance storage is configurable in `nifi.properties`.  You should take a look at the [Persistent Provenance Repository Properties](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#persistent-provenance-repository-properties) section, which controls the provenance record retention by both time and total size of the provenance data set.  The defaults are 24 hours / 1 GB.

```
# Persistent Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.directory.default=./provenance_repository
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.time=24 hours
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.size=1 GB
```